# How do I set my keyboard to Canadian Multilingual and make it stick through reboots?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard-layout

The layout is nowhere to be seen in the keyboard options.
18.04.3 LTS

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpdIh.png have you gone through this?

Comment: No I had not gone through that. As it turns out, Ubuntu likes to use the same names for keyboard layouts and layout categories. So When I saw "French (Canada)" listed in the prompt that comes up after clicking the + button, I did not click it because that layout was already installed and it wasn't the layout I was looking for. Lo and behold, that wasn't a keyboard layout, but a category that was hiding load of other keyboard layouts.

Comment: by going through other I found Canadian multilingual. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKCOD.png

Answer (score 1):

The list that comes up after clicking the + button under "Input Sources" in "Language and Region" settings is not a list of keyboard layouts. It is a list of categories that contain keyboard layouts. Clicking one of these items in the list reveals more keyboard layouts. The layout I was looking for is under French (Canada).